# equivalent of $(document).ready(function(){}) in clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

how implement $(document).ready(function(){}) in clojurescript. 
I tried this:

```
 (. ready js/document ());;but i am trying to achieve the callback function
```

But doesn't seem right to me. Any ideas?

new to clojurescript so i am bit confused as to how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
(.addEventListener
  js/window
  "DOMContentLoaded"
  (fn [] (.log js/console "DOMContentLoaded callback")))
```

Answer (score 3):

**For simply a clojurescript entry point, you may implement a main function in e.g. the core namespace:**

```
(ns app.core)

(defn main []
  (activate-app))
```

Then call the entry point at the end of the module:

```
(main)
```

The idea is to have the entry point main function called *after* all code has been loaded. Hence the module with the entry point call should not itself be required by any other modules.

A variation sets up an **entry point explicitly called from javascript** after the compiled clojurescript has been loaded:

```
(defn ^:export main []
  (activate-app))

(set! js/cljs-entry-point main)
```

This entry point can now be called from a script element at the bottom of the body of the associated html document:

```
<script>cljs_entry_point()</script>
```

A benefit with the latter approach is that other modules still can require the module containing the entry point.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a function main which calls a number of other functions.

```
(defn main []
  (app-instruction-1)
  (app-instruction-2))

(set! (.-onload js/window) main)
```